# How can I include the citation string, but not the reference in the end?

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I would like to use the `\cite{}` command in certain places, which will include the string *Smith (YYYY)* in the text, but will *not* add the actual reference in the end under "References".

Is there a way to do it? I am using bibtex and natbib.

Comment: Then, one how does know what *Smith (YYYY)* refers to?

Comment: With Biblatex it can be done, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218527/how-to-put-a-full-citation-in-the-text-without-adding-an-entry-to-the-bibliogr.

Comment: Another option might be to manually edit the `.bbl` file and remove the entries that you don't want. Note that when you run Bibtex again the `.bbl` file will be recreated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not really possible to filter out entries with natbib. But you can write the name-year info to the aux-file manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\cite{smith} \cite{doody}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\makeatletter
\NAT@wrout{}{1975}{Smith}{}{smith}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image]